# Where to put forum in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, ipb

I am trying to create laravel 5.2 project with ipb forum.
So i am looking after a best practice. Where i should put forum directory in laravel. Maybe "/resources/forum" or in "/public/forum" directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install your IPB forum into `/public/forum`. Then, you will need to setup your web server, so `forum` directory work properly.

For `Apache` your can add something like this into `.htaccess` inside a `public` directory:

```
RewriteRule ^forum - [L,NC]
```

To make it work, you should put this rule before all other rules.

Also, I'd recommend you to integrate Laravel auth system with IPB for better user experience. You can use package, similar to [has-lv](https://github.com/has-lv/ipbwi).

Comment: Thanks for help and i already found that package, but thanks anyway. :)